# Webreference vs servicereference. Only one works ? Serialization?

Tags: c#, web-services, service-reference

I've got two applications.

One uses webreference to my webservice, and second use servicereference to my webservice.

There is metohod which I'm invoking:

```
[WebMethod]
public Car[] GetCars(string carCode)
{
 Cars[] cars= ModelToContract.ToCars(MyFacade.GetCars(carCode);
return cars;
}
```

Car has two pools:

```
string Code {get;set;}
CarType Type {get;set;}

public enum CarType
{
Van=0,
Pickup=1
}
```

I'm debuging this webMethod, and...

at the end webservice throw good collection of cars, which has one car:
code="bmw",Type.Van

But...
Application with webrefence receives the same collection
and application with servicereference gets collection, where field code is null...

Invoking servicereference:

```
MyService myService=new MyService()
Cars[] cars= client.GetCars(carcode);
```

Invoking webservice:

```
MyService.MyServiceSoapClient client = new MyServiceS.MyServiceSoapClient();
            Cars[] cars= client.GetCars(carcode);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hum it's a serialization problem.

Your model should be like this :

```
[Serializable]
public class Car
{
    [XmlElement]
    string Code {get;set;}

    [XmlElement]
    CarType Type {get;set;}
}
```

You may ensure the return type too :

```
MyService myService=new MyService()
MyService.Car[] cars= myService.GetCars(carcode);
```

-

```
MyServiceS.MyServiceSoapClient client = new MyServiceS.MyServiceSoapClient();
MyServiceS.Car[] cars= client.GetCars(carcode);
```

Comment: Yes, that now works for service references, but doesn't work for webreference :/

Comment: You may have to redefine the references if not already done to regenerate the model on the client-side.

Comment: Actually, `[Serializable]` is not used by XML Serialization.

Comment: True its for binary Serialization. It's just a good practice for entities.